# Inline-editable fields goes away on clicking them

Tags: grid, field, atk4

When I just load the page there are all the fields, but when I click on them, then the clicked field just disappears. However, no changes are applied to DB.

This is the code:

```
function page_users_listing($p){
            $g = $this->add('Grid');
            $g->addColumn('inline','first_name');
            $g->addColumn('inline','last_name');
            $g->addColumn('text','telephone');
            $g->addColumn('expander','comments');
            $g->setSource('client');
        }
```

What could I missing?

Comment: minor note is that you should add Grid to a page. I suppose $this refers no $api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work fine with 4.0.3.

http://codepad.agiletoolkit.org/editablef

If you are on 4.1 branch it might have something to do with changes to "reloading" mechanism and is a bug.

Comment: I guess there's a problem in the way I'm adding the grid object to the page. I'll try based on your shared code and will be back if the issue persists.
BTW: 4.0.3/master

Comment: another guess is that you might have lost some of the GET arguments. Try to make sure you made them sticky through $this->api->stickyGET('id').

Comment: Found it!

The problem was that I was adding the Grid to "$this" instead of "$p".
Common mistake when copy/pasting code. :(  Solved!